# INDEX Issue when Adding Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an issue when using `INDEX`. The `INDEX` function works fine if I delete a row from the targeted sheet using:

```
INDEX(MissionList!$B$3:$B$36,1,1)
```

The problem is that if I add row(s) to the top of the MissionList sheet then I have to manually reset my formula to see the value.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Where have you got stuck? [superuser.com/help/how-to-ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent range from changing when you add / delete cells you can use [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

In your example use

- `INDIRECT("MissionList!$B$3:$B$36")`
- instead of `MissionList!$B$3:$B$36`